# Android Edit Text Cursor position doesn't change in first time

Tags: android, android-edittext

I want to **change position of Cursor** in `EditText` after **click on EditText**

I want change position Cursor to between ten - twelve after click, With click in **first time**.

[image: Image of text]

Here's my code:

```
final EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    editText.setText(text1 + text2);
    editText.setSelection(text1.length());

    editText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            editText.setSelection(editText.getText().length() - text2.length());
        }
    });

    editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
            if (!editable.toString().contains(text1) || !editable.toString().contains(text2)) {
                editText.setText(text1 + text2);
                editText.setSelection(text1.length());
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Try to add your Code here, so that we can help easily.

Comment: Use edittext.setonFocusListener component and you can set selection onFocusChange method with on the listener interface.

Comment: Your question in unclear. Please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I keep it simple, the following snippet is sufficiently enough to achieve what you want (apparently)

```
final EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
editText.setText(text1 + text2);
// Keep it simple for the selection, it will place the cursor at end of text1
editText.setSelection(text1.length());
// editText.setCursorVisible(true); // I don't think it is required

// You don't need to go for OnTouchListener, OnClickListener will do for you
editText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        editText.setSelection(editText.getText().length() - text2.length());
    }
});

editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
        if (!editable.toString().contains(text1) || !editable.toString().contains(text2)) {
            editText.setText(text1 + text2);
            editText.setSelection(text1.length());
        }
    }
});
```

#### UPDATE 1

The above code works fine if it is the first EditText to gain focus, otherwise, if soft keyboard is already open, the cursor at first is shown at tapped place. Here's a work around for this (not the best solution, but it will work for you)

```
editText.setCursorVisible(false);
editText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean hasFocus) {
        if (hasFocus) {
            editText.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    editText.setSelection(editText.getText().length() - text2.length());
                    editText.setCursorVisible(true);
                }
            });
        } else {
            editText.setCursorVisible(false);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: This is very good but don't change position for first click, other click is Ok

Comment: @mohammadjafari For the first click? The first click automatically goes to the selection, doesn't it? Please recheck you have copied all lines properly. If the issue still exist, then update your question with the updated code and screenshot

Comment: Updated, first click is going to the position of click and i don't want this, I want going to end text1 with first click.

Answer (score 0):

Use should use android:imeOptions="actionNext" in your xml EditText. This will help you.

Comment: Don't work this, after click still position is on my finger click

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure please try

```
editText.setText(text1 + text2);
editText.setSelection(editText.getText().length() - text2.length());
editText.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
         @Override
         public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
           (EditText)view.setSelection((EditText)view.getText().length() - text2.length());
           return false;
         }
      });
```

Comment: What error?  I only asked to type cast the view to Edittext and put a set selection outside

Comment: I think view can't cast to `EditText` in this code.

Comment: Try making view final

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Selection.setSelection use editText.setSelection()